# Assign IP address to a Virtual Printer

Tags: printing, ip, network-printer, tcpip

Is it possible to assign an IP to a virtual PDF Printer? Is there any Virtual printer software that automatically can do this?

Comment: What are you actually asking for here?  Do you want to share a PDF printer with others on the network?  What OS?

Comment: #Paul: I am needing to print off a label for it from other computers. But i need to have an IP address to that printer and not a network address (ex: network=\\blah\blah vs. IP=192.168.44.33) or the script we use to print wont work (or wont find the printer). Windows 7.

Comment: The script doesn't support SMB printing?  So only lpr perhaps?  I don't know how you could do this with Windows, but you can use linux CUPS + cups-pdf.

Comment: @Paul: No it wouldnt work. I has to be an IP address.

Comment: Do you know what protocol the script uses?

Comment: Its a MS SQL base table it takes it out of. It also has the printer template layout as well in there. It's an intermec printer. I just dont want to waste paper when all i really want is the image it prints out.

Comment: install Print&Share, share the printer and access it by \\computerIPaddress\sharename to print? see www.printandshare.info

Answer (score -1):

I don't don't believe you can assign an IP address to a virtual printer but you may be able to setup a "direct virtual printer" that listens for incoming jobs on a TCP/IP port.  A caveat is the output has to already be in a format your PDF printer is looking for or you will have to setup some sort of intermediate conversion process. See this [link](https://www.printdistributor.com/help/virtual_printers.html) for more details.  See this [StackOverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61945604/3473225) for an example of listening on a port and redirecting the input to a virtual GhostScript printer - credit goes to beginner6789.